# Where is shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am so frustrated right now after several hours trying to find where shared_ptr is located. None of the examples I see show complete code to include the headers for `shared_ptr` (and working). Simply stating `std`, `tr1` and `<memory>` is not helping at all! I have downloaded boosts and all but still it doesn't show up!  Can someone help me by telling exactly where to find it?

Thanks for letting me vent my frustrations!

EDIT:
I see my title has been changed. Sorry about that.
So... it was also because it was not clear to me that shared_ptr is "C++ version dependant" --> that's why I did not state my environment --> therefore probably why it was so difficult for me to find it.

I am working on MSVS2008.

EDIT 2:
I don't know why,  but I was including [memory] and [boost/tr1/memory.hpp] and [boost/tr1/tr1/memory] while looking everywhere for the shared_ptr.. of course, i couldn't.

Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: probably it will be helpful if you can state your setup correctly, like what compiler and boost version/installation path

Comment: Unless you're on C++0x, `shared_ptr` is not part of the standard. It's so common though that some will treat it as standard even though it's not in yet.

Comment: How do you think we should answer this question without knowing whether your environment is GCC for a 7.5bit dishwasher chip, a 128bit mainframe's proprietary compiler, or XCode's version of GCC?

Comment: Just to add some info about the problem I faced.. If you want to compile with c++0x standard you need to add "-std=c++0x" as argument of g++.

Comment: If you're on MSVC, then you just need "#include <memory>" (for gcc, I have a CMake Find() for searching so that I can declare preprocessor definition to include either <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> versus <tr1/shared_ptr.h> as first choice being tr1 over boost - note that boost is "hpp" while tr1 is ".h" - verified on Gentoo/Fedora/Debian - and of course make sure to also have #include <memory> for memory management separately)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

There are at least three places where you may find `shared_ptr`:

1. If your C++ implementation supports C++11 (or at least the C++11 `shared_ptr`), then `std::shared_ptr` will be defined in `<memory>`.
2. If your C++ implementation supports the C++ TR1 library extensions, then `std::tr1::shared_ptr` will likely be in `<memory>` (Microsoft Visual C++) or `<tr1/memory>` (g++'s libstdc++).  Boost also provides a TR1 implementation that you can use.
3. Otherwise, you can obtain the Boost libraries and use `boost::shared_ptr`, which can be found in `<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>`.

Comment: For VS 2008, did you get the "feature pack" or did you install SP1? If so then part 2 here applies to you, use the namespace `tr1`.

Comment: Thanks. This works like magic. I don't know why,  but I was including <memory> and <boost/tr1/memory.hpp> and <boost/tr1/tr1/memory> while looking everywhere for the shared_ptr.. of course, i couldn't. Thanks again.

Comment: Having stepped away from C++ briefly I was surprised to find that (in clang v3.1) `shared_ptr` was still sitting in a `tr1` namespace. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @hiwaylon:  Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Yessir, unfortunately that caused some unhappiness with other dependencies and I was unable to continue (given time constraints). If **-std=c++11** is the trick, I can continue with confidence when I am able to return to the project. Thank you.

Comment: kinda already mentioned, but `#include <memory>` along with `std::shared_ptr` only worked for me after explicitly adding the `-std=c++11` flag to `g++` version 5.3.1

Answer (score 7):

[Boost Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/index.html)

[If you want to use it from Boost TR1 instead](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/usage.html#boost_tr1.usage.include_style)

[shared_ptr Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/example/shared_ptr_example.cpp)

Answer (score 6):

for VS2008 with feature pack update, shared_ptr can be found under namespace std::tr1.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> MyIntSmartPtr = new int;
```

of

if you had boost installation path (for example @ `C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_40_0`) added to your IDE settings:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your'e looking bor [boost](http://www.boost.org/)'s [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), you could have easily found the answer by [googling shared_ptr](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1SNNT_ENUS346&q=shared_ptr&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), following the links to the docs, and pulling up a complete working example such as [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/example/shared_ptr_example.cpp).

In any case, here is a minimalistic complete working example for you which I just hacked up:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct MyGizmo
{
    int n_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<MyGizmo> p(new MyGizmo);
    return 0;
}
```

In order for the `#include` to find the header, the libraries obviously need to be in the search path.  In MSVC, you set this in Project Settings>Configuration Properties>C/C++>Additional Include Directories.  In my case, this is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42`