# C++ Reorganizing an array to fill in the gaps?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm not sure if the word *Reorganizing* is the correct term, but its the only way I can describe what I'm looking for.

If I have an array of say, Cats, like so:

```
CAT *myCats[99];

myCats[0] = new CAT;
myCats[1] = new CAT;
myCats[2] = new CAT;
myCats[3] = new CAT;
myCats[4] = new CAT;
myCats[5] = new CAT;
```

At one point in time, lets say myCats[3] gets deleted:

```
delete myCats[3];
```

now I have the following:

```
myCats[0]
myCats[1]
myCats[2]
myCats[4]
myCats[5]
```

Is there an easy way to *reorganize* the array so that it moves 4->3 and 5->4, essentially filling in the gaps?

```
myCats[0]
myCats[1]
myCats[2]
myCats[3]
myCats[4]
```

Is the best way to accomplish this, to essentially iterate through the array and determining that if a element is empty/missing, I just need to move the next existing element into its place? How would I do this?  How would I determine if the Cat element at any point in the array exists? Or is there a more simple pre-determined method for accomplishing what I need?

Sorry if the example and syntax is a little off. I'm new to C++.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the quick suggestions. Looks like Vectors are the way to go. I always forget about Vectors. In the front of my mind, a Vector is just a container that holds an x, y and z value :-)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately arrays are highly visible in C++ with their natural syntax while vectors, which are usually better, are not. I also think the world would be a better place if smart pointers were somehow the "default" pointer type in C++, with `raw_pointer<T>` being a bolted-on extension for experts concerned with performance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using C++, you can much more easily accomplish this using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<CAT*> cats;
cats.push_back(new CAT);
cats.push_back(new CAT);
cats.push_back(new CAT);

// remove the second cat
delete cats[1];
cats.erase(cats.begin() + 1);
```

Now the vector has two cats in it (the first and third cats that were inserted) and they are at indices zero and one.

However, in C++, there's no reason to allocate everything dynamically, so you're likely to be better off with just a `vector<CAT>`:

```
std::vector<CAT> cats;
cats.push_back(CAT());
cats.push_back(CAT());
cats.push_back(CAT());

// remove the second cat
cats.erase(cats.begin() + 1);
```

This way, destruction of the cats is handled automatically and you don't have to worry about managing any of the memory yourself.

If you *do* have to use pointers (e.g., your class is a polymorphic base class), you'd probably want to use a `std::vector` of smart pointers (e.g., `shared_ptr`s).  With smart pointers, you don't have to remember to delete the objects when you are done with them--it gets done automatically.  For example, the above code using `shared_ptr` would look like:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CAT> > cats;
cats.push_back(std::make_shared(new CAT));
cats.push_back(std::make_shared(new CAT));
cats.push_back(std::make_shared(new CAT));

// remove the second cat
// note we don't need to call delete; shared_ptr does that for us
cats.erase(cats.begin() + 1);
```

(Your standard library may not include `shared_ptr` in the `std` namespace yet; in that case, [you may find it elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918202/where-is-shared-ptr/2918235#2918235)).  If you aren't familiar with `shared_ptr`, [the Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) makes for a great introduction.

Comment: Yes, `vector<CAT*>` is better than array of `CAT *`, but as the OP is new to C++, I suspect `vector<CAT>` would cover his use case and be much better (safer + easier) again.

Comment: @j_random_hacker:  Oh; that's a good point.  I shouldn't post answers before I've had some coffee.  I added an example using a `vector<CAT>`.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

as others have pointed out using std::vector would do all the reallocation for you, it is still going to be an O(n) operation though. however you may be able to do even better with another data structure. e.g. std::list would allow you remove an element from anywhere in the list in O(1).

ultimately which datastructure is most appropriate will depend on all the operations you need to support on it, their relative frequency and the performance you need from each.

Comment: Good point about each individual deletion being O(n) for a `vector`. If you can decide whether an element should be deleted by looking at it in isolation, then one way out would be to use a single `remove_if()` to perform all deletions in a single O(n) pass. (Counterintuitively, this requires a subsequent call to `erase()`.)

Comment: yes remove_if and however else the OP is using the container may well make vector the right choice, but as we can only see they want to remove elements from the middle it is pretty hard to objectively recomend one container over another

Answer (score 1):

You could assign `NULL` to the pointer after deleting and then check if the pointer is NULL or keep an array of bools of the same size which would indicate if that object is there or not. As for reorganizing: If order does matter, then you have to move all the elements as described. If the order does NOT matter, simply move the last element into the missing gap.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you can't use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead of an array? Vector is automatically sizing so you wouldn't have to worry about this.