# How do I handle constant object when implementing shared pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, c++03

Due to project restrictions, I can't use boost or more modern C++. I have implemented a shared pointer that works for my project needs but I'm struggling with handling constant objects.

I need to be able to do something like -

`SharedPtr<MyData> sp(new MyData());
SharedPtr<const MyData> const_sp(sp);`

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Check whether your environment has the TR1 extensions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2918235/103167   Using `std::tr1::shared_ptr` will be a lot less painful than rolling your own, you've only scratched the surface of how complicated it gets.

Comment: I was looking for a quick and dirty shared pointer implementation. Due to nature of the project, didn't have access to either of those three libraries. Thanks for the link though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a templated copy-constructor which will allow you to copy-construct from `SharedPtr` instances with a compatible template argument:

```
template <typename T>
class SharedPtr {
    template <typename U>
    SharedPtr (const SharedPtr<U> &rhs);
}
```